# variable `-name` primary to `find`

Tags: shell, find, quoting

I am trying to construct a compound `-name` primary for the `find` command from an arbitrary number of strings in an array, of the form `\( -name ${a[0]} -or -name ${a[1]} -or -name ${a[2]} ... \)`. While explicitly typing the name primary into the terminal works, storing it in a variable and recalling it by parameter expansion does not. Since expansion will take place before `find` runs, I assume the problem has something to do with quoting of the expanded variable.

Below is a minimal example for n=2 names, either typed literally or recalled from a variable. While I realize that I could pipe to `grep`, I would prefer to do everything with `find` in this case.

```
$ ls
a1  a2  b1  b2  c1  c2

$ find . \( -name a\* -or -name b\* \)
./a1
./a2
./b1
./b2

$ names="\( -name a\* -or -name b\* \)"

$ printf "%s\n" "$names"
\( -name a\* -or -name b\* \)

$ find . $(printf "%q" "$names")
find: -name\: unknown primary or operator

$ find . $(printf "%s" "$names")
find: \): unknown primary or operator

$ find . $names
find: \): unknown primary or operator

$ find . "$names"
find: \( -name a\* -or -name b\* \): No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `-name`, each `-or`, each parenthesis and each pattern must be a separate argument to `find`. Don't concatenate the arguments with spaces in between: you can't go back from there to a list of arguments — how could you know which spaces are there to separate arguments and which spaces are part of an argument? See also [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

If your shell supports arrays (ksh, bash, zsh), store the list of arguments in an array.

```
names=(\( -name a\* -or -name b\* \))
…
find "${names[@]}"
```

If your shell doesn't support arrays, you can construct the list in the positional arguments (the arguments that you can access as `$1`, `$2`, …). The obvious limitation is that you can't use the positional arguments for another purpose.

```
set -- \( -name a\* -or -name b\* \)
…
find "$@"
```