# Using linux 'find' command's multiple name feature in a variable?

Tags: linux, shell, find, variable

I newly learned how to search multiple file names with `find` like:

```
find . \( -iname "*.srt" -o -iname "*.mp4" \)
```

But in some cases I had to use so many filters like this and that simple command line became so long:

```
find . \( -iname "*.srt" -o ......... \)
```

Can I create a variable and add this all filters in it, then use it again in find command? Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [variable \`-name\` primary to \`find\`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/456863/variable-name-primary-to-find)

Comment: Storing commands (or parts of commands) in variables is problematic (see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)). If you're running `find` repeatedly with the same list of patterns, a function would be a much better choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the GNU implementation of `find`, there is another way to search multiple file names:

```
rgx='.*\.srt\|.*\.mp4'
find . -iregex "$rgx"
```

The `\|` is the logical regex OR (in the default regexps types of GNU `find` which are the emacs ones). A naked `.` means any char. and a dot is `\.`.

You could define a `$rgx_compr` and a `$rgx_media`, and then combine it:

```
find . -iregex "$rgx_compr" -o -iregex "$rgx_media"
```

I left out the parens here.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using a shell that supports array variables (i.e. `bash`) you can create an array variable and use that directly.

Constant expression

```
find . \( -iname "*.srt" -o -iname "*.mp4" \) ...
```

Variable expression

```
opts=(-iname "*.srt" -o -iname "*.mp4")
find \( "${opts[@]}" \) ...
```

Or

```
opts=( '(' -iname "*.srt" -o -iname "*.mp4" ')' )
find "${opts[@]}" ...
```

Notice that the array variable expansion itself must be double-quoted (`"${opts[@]}"`) even though it contains one or more items. If the array contains no items it will expand to *nothing* (not the empty string, `""`).

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it is possible. With the method I show below, take care of the usage of quotations, wildcards, etc. Nonetheless, here is one solution in `BASH`:

```
opt="-iname '*.srt' -o -iname '*.mp4'"
find . \( $(eval echo ${opt}) \)
```

While it is not possible to simply call the `${opt}` variable in the `find` command, we can work around it by using the `eval` command in `$(eval echo ${opt})` line.

Comment: This answer has problems. `eval` is full of traps for the unwary, and I don't recommend using it unless you have a deep understanding of shell parsing. In this case, it'll have trouble if there are matching files directly in the current directory. (And there are some other, weirder problems here.)