# find "paths must precede expression" when substituting command results

Tags: bash, shell-script, find

I am trying to run `find` to exclude a list of directories that I have in a file.  This file is used by a different command as well so I am stuck with the format of the file, which is each line contains the directory name "as is" followed by a slash, e.g.

```
My Files/
```

I tried various things such as xargs which I could not get to work but finally settled on pre-processing the blacklist to produce the arguments to find like this:

```
find . -type f $(cat .blacklist.txt | while read -r line; do printf "! -path './%s*' -prune " "$line"; done)
```

However, whenever I encounter a directory name in the blacklist which has spaces in it, I get the error:

```
find: paths must precede expression: `<Last Part Of Name>/*''
```

I used `set -x` to try to figure out what is going on, and it appears that the separate parts of the directory name are being individually quoted.  For instance, suppose I have a directory name in the list called "My Files".  I see this output from `set -x` for this particular line of the file:

```
++ printf '! -path '\''./%s*'\'' -prune ' 'My Files/'
```

So far so good I think.  But when I see the output of this in the final assembled command, it looks like this:

```
'!' -path ''\''./My' 'Files/*'\''' -prune
```

The problem is obvious: it's turning my directory name which I worked so hard to keep in one piece, into two pieces!  But I can't see why it would be doing this.  I have tried a few variations, for instance instead of:

```
printf "! -path './%s*' -prune " "$line"
```

I think that somehow I need to make sure that the resulting output of the path is quoted when it comes out of the printf, but I have tried all of these and none of them worked:

```
printf "! -path \"./%s*\" -prune " "$line"
printf "! -path "'./$line*'" -prune "
printf "! -path '"./$line*"' -prune "
```

But none of these stopped the individual words in the directory name from being split apart.

I also tried this:

```
printf "! -path ./%s* -prune " "$line"
```

This avoids splitting the directory name, but as it's no longer quoted it is getting expanded into all the sub-directories under that path which is wrong and also breaks the command as now there are multiple sub-directories where only one directory is expected.

It also does not seem to matter if I use `%s` followed by the argument as a separate parameter to `printf`, or if I substitute `%s` with `$line` directly.

Comment: You should probably be assembling the arguments into an *array* - see for example [Using linux 'find' command's multiple name feature in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/559604/65304)

Comment: @steeldriver aside from the fact that I can't seem to get the completed array out of the loop when I'm done (it's a sub-process, and all the solutions to get the results out seem to destroy the whole point of having subprocesses) how do I get the values *into* the array properly in the first place?  With `set -x` I'm still seeing the parts of the directory name get split up.

Comment: @steeldriver I found a fix but it's basically to construct the entire command including the find and then eval the entire string, but I'm not sure I understand the implications of eval well enough to know if there is a security hole here...

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/559604/100397

Answer (score 4):

I'd do this with `perl`'s [File::Find](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Find) module because constructing long `find` commands with lots of predicates is a PITA compared to just writing a simple procedural script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use File::Find;
use autodie qw(open);

# load the blacklist into an array
my @blacklist;
open(my $BL,"<","blacklist.txt");
while(<$BL>) {
  # Assume one directory per line. Paths are treated
  # as regular expressions, not as literal strings.
  chomp;
  push @blacklist, $_;
};
close($BL);

# generate a regexp to match all the entries in the array
our $blacklist_re = "^(?:" . join("|",@blacklist) . ")";
#print "$blacklist_re\n";

find { wanted => \&wanted, preprocess => \&prune }, '.';

sub wanted { -f && print "$File::Find::name\n" };
sub prune  { return grep { ! -d || ! m/$blacklist_re/ } @_ };
```

Updated 2023-04-24 - this version actually prunes the unwanted directories by using a preprocess subroutine, so that `File::Find` doesn't descend into them.

The preprocess subroutine `prune` is called every time `find` enters into a directory (including any directories given as args to the `find` function, `.` in this case).

The filenames (including dirs, sockets, device nodes etc) in a dir are passed as an array to `prune`, which returns an array of filenames which either aren't directories OR don't match the blacklist regexp. This uses perl's built-in `grep` function - this is not the external `/bin/grep` command, it operates on lists/arrays instead of files. See `perldoc -f grep`.

Any filenames NOT in the array returned by prune are excluded from further processing by `find`, so the `wanted` subroutine has been simplified to just a `-f` test - `wanted` never even sees pruned directories or files.

###### Sample Run:

With a `blacklist.txt` file containing the following:

```
foo bar
bar baz
```

and creating those directories and some dummy files:

```
mkdir 'foo bar' 'bar baz' 
touch 'bar baz/a.txt' 'foo bar/b.txt' 'foo bar/c.txt'
touch d.txt
```

so that the directory structure looks like this:

```
.
├── bar baz
│   └── a.txt
├── blacklist.txt
├── d.txt
├── ff.pl
├── foo bar
    ├── b.txt
    └── c.txt
```

Running the script (after saving it as, e.g., `ff.pl`, and making it executable with `chmod +x ff.pl`) produces the following output:

```
$ ./ff.pl 
./ff.pl
./blacklist.txt
./d.txt
```

i.e. the directores in blacklist.txt are excluded from the output.

Comment: oh wow, thanks! I didn't know about %q.  I'll test this out as soon as I get a check and then accept.

Comment: `%q` won't help here, the output of that sloop is split with split+glob which doesn't understand quotes (and you don't want the glob part). Those ANDed together `! -path ... -prune ` likely don't make sense either

Answer (score 4):

If the intention is to find regular files, skipping the ones in directories whose paths followed by a `/` are listed in `.blacklist.txt` one per line, then with that file containing:

```
my dir/
 my [other] dir?/sub dir/
```

for instance, you'd need to call find with these arguments:

0. `find`
1. `.`
2. `(`
3. `-path`
4. `./my dir`
5. `-o`
6. `-path`
7. `./ my \[other\] dir\?/sub dir` (`[` and `?` escaped as otherwise they're treated specially by `find`'s `-path`; escaping `]` shouldn't be necessary in most `find` implementations but won't harm)
8. `)`
9. `-prune` # prune the ones matched above
10. `-o` # anything else:
11. `-type`
12. `f` # files of type "regular"
13. `-print`

So you need for each line:

- to remove the trailing `/`
- to escape the characters special to `-path`: `\?*[]`
- prepend `./`
- prepend a `-path` line

Then put a `-o` argument in between each, and collect the resulting lines into a list to pass to `find`.

To do that splitting, in the bash shell, you can do it with `readarray -t` and in `zsh` with the `f` parameter expansion flag. You could use split+glob like you did by omitting the quotes around `$(...)`, but you'd need first to set `$IFS` to newline only and disable the glob part which we don't want here (not done in zsh) with `set -o noglob`

In `bash`:

```
readarray -t args < <(
  sed 's|/$||
       s|[][\\?*]|\\&|g
       s|^|./|
       1!i\
-o
       i\
-path' .blacklist.txt
)
find . '(' "${args[@]}" ')' -prune -o -type f -print
```

In zsh:

```
find . '(' ${(f)"$(
  sed 's|/$||
       s/[][\\?*]/\\&/g
       s|^|./|
       1!i\
-o
       i\
-path' .blacklist.txt)"} ')' -prune -o -type f -print
```

`zsh` has the `b` parameter expansion flag to escape glob operators, and in that shell, you could use globbing with the `N`ullglob qualifier to reduce the blacklist to directories that actually exist and `P`repend the `-o` and `-path` arguments.

```
() {
  find . '(' $@[2,-1] ')' -prune -o -type f -print
} ./${(f)^"$(<.blacklist.txt)"}(Ne['REPLY=${(b)REPLY%/}']P[-o]P[-path])
```

Here, we're `P` prepending both `-o` and `-path` to every file using the `P` glob qualifier, passing the list to an anonymous function and and passing the second to last argument to `find` (`$@[2,-1]`). Given that you likely want to omit `.blacklist.txt` itself from the result, you could also do:

```
find . '(' -path ./.blacklist.txt ./${(f)^"$(<.blacklist.txt)"}(Ne['REPLY=${(b)REPLY%/}']P[-o]P[-path]) ')' -prune -o -type f -print
```

If you have GNU `find` or compatible, an alternative to `-path` that doesn't require having to do that escaping, removing the trailing `/` or prepending `./` is to use `-samefile`:

```
find . '(' -samefile .blacklist.txt ${(f)^"$(<.blacklist.txt)"}(NP[-o]P[-path]) ')' -prune -o -type f -print
```

Answer (score 4):

> and it appears that the separate parts of the directory name are being individually quoted.

I wouldn't say that. What happens is that when you print e.g. `! -path './My Files*' -prune` from a command substitution, it gets word-split into `!`, `-path`, `'./My`, `Files*'`, `-prune` as the word-splitting step doesn't process syntax like quotes, but only looks at whitespace characters (or what ever you've set `IFS` to). That `Files*'` would also act as a glob, but you likely don't have filenames that end in a single quote.

The quotes you see in the `set -x` output are there because Bash makes that output valid as input to the shell for display. The escaped quote there is the one you printed from `printf`.

Here, you need to produce `!`, `-path`, `./My Files*`, `-prune` as distinct arguments to `find`. One way to do that is to collect the arguments in an array.

```
#!/bin/bash
args=()
filename='./My Files'
args+=( ! -path "$filename*" -prune )
# etc.
find . -type f "${args[@]}"
```

But  you likely really need
that as

```
find . -type f ! -path './somedir/*' ! -path './otherdir/*'
```

(without the `-prune`, walking the whole tree including the listed directories, just ignoring anything in them), or like Stéphane Chazelas shows in their answer,

```
find . \( -path ./somedir -o -path ./otherdir \) -prune -o -type f -print
```

(not even descending into the listed directories, you need to escape `()` for the shell).

*And* if the excluded names can contain characters that are special for `find`'s pattern matching (`*?[`), you need to escape those with a backslash, along with any backslashes.

If we use the former pattern, and ignore the escaping:

```
#!/bin/bash
args=(-type f)
while read -r filename; do
    args+=( ! -path "./$filename/*" )
done < excluded.txt
find . "${args[@]}"
```

the better way is a bit more involved, something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
args=()
first=1
while read -r escaped; do
    if [ "$first" != 1 ]; then
        args+=( -o )
    fi
    args+=( -path "./$escaped" )
    first=0
done < <(sed -e 's/[[?*\]/\\&/g' < excluded.txt)
find . \( "${args[@]}" \) -prune -o -type f -print
```

(here, also using a process substitution (`<(cmd...)`) to pipe the list of filenames through sed for escaping)

The key when building the array is to put the arguments in the assignment exactly as you'd put them in a command, and not e.g. add any extra quotes. Then when using the array, you must just the `"${args[@]}"` syntax, noting the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd probably do (assuming `bash` and GNU `find`):

```
find . -exec fgrep -qx \{} $(sed 's#/$##' .blacklist.txt) \; -prune -o -type f -print
```

It is not very efficient if the blacklist is long, but it works with most filenames. (*Most*: e.g. filenames with newlines in them are still an issue.)

Comment: There's nothing specific to bash or GNU find in there, but that won't work as you're passing the edited contents of `.blacklist.txt` subject to split+glob to `fgrep` while you want to pass the path to a file containing that edited contents, so you'd need zsh and something like `-exec grep -Fqx '{}' =(sed 's|/$||' .blacklist.txt) ';'`

Comment: Note that it's not efficient even if the blacklist is short as it spawns one process and executes one `fgrep` (likely a lot more expensive than looking up text in that file unless the blacklist is huge) for each file.

Comment: It may not be efficient, but it does work (I tested it) and it is relatively easy to write.